# How do I make a Simple SOAP request in CiviCRM?

Tags: api, civicrm-home, soap

As I can see there is a get_contact() function in CRM/Utils/SoapServer.php.
I would like to use this function to get the list of contact. How can I do that ? Is it similar to how we make a Rest api call like `http://<site_name>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/soap.php?` ? If it is, what params do I need to pass to get the required result ?

Any help/hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update : I'm using the latest version of CiviCRM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a proper answer to the question of how to use `SoapServer`, but it may be useful to place that in context.

The `extern/soap.php` script is a bit of a relic which is not on par with the RESTy APIv3. I was just a casual user at the time, but I'm pretty sure it predates APIv3 and (probably) APIv2. Its major use-case was facilitating a fast return-channel for CiviMail. (There's some kind of smtpd/perl/soap integration which folks used to use.) IMHO, the only reason to retain it in the codebase is for backward compatibility (on the off-chance that it maybe still works for existing installations).

If you skim the code of [`CRM_Utils_SoapServer`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/SoapServer.php), you'll see `get_contact()` and a bunch of mail-related actions (and basically nothing else). The design is generally... shallow.

If you really do need SOAP access, then I'd recommend implementing new bindings between SOAP and APIv3. Ideally:

- The SOAP implementation should be generic, passing along requests to `civicrm_api3()` and getting metadata from `civicrm_api3` (ie `Entity.get` and `*.getfields`).
- The SOAP end-point should ideally go through the menu/router system -- rather than a standalone script (e.g. `http://example.com/civicrm/soap` instead of `http://example.com/sites/something/modules/civicrm/extern/soap.php`).
- The SOAP end-point should ideally go into an extension.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Now, I get a proper idea of my findings related to this:)